# Ready to publish but don't get publish option

Tags: android

I am new in android programming.
Recently I have finished my android apps.
I have a account in Google Developer Console.
I have upload my apk file and also Graphs.
My APK is ok and Store Listing is OK and Pricing & Distribution is ok.
It shows ready to publish your apps but i don't get publish option.

-My question is how log time take to show publish option.
- what is the error 
- why publish don't show please help me.

Answer (score 6):

Logout and login once worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Publish your draft**

Click the Draft button, then click Publish to queue your app for publishing on Google Play. If you haven’t met the publishing requirements, click the **Why can’t I publish?** button to see a list of unmet requirements.

Refer This:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3502619?hl=en